# File explorer for Android devices

Tags: android, file

Does the Android platform provide the ability to get a list of all files and their sizes stored on an Android device?
What I need is to find or write an explorer type of application.

Answer (score 0):

Tre ESFileExplorer from [www.estrongs.com](http://www.estrongs.com)